# sed insert before specific character

Tags: insert, sed

Im trying to sed insert:

```
echo "usr_web88_2" | sed 's/^\(usr\_\)'
```

but I can't find a solution

I have this string:

```
usr_web88_2
```

and want to add backslashes before the underscores like this:

```
usr\_web88\_2
```

Can anybody help me? thank you..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo "usr_web88_2" | sed 's/_/\\_/g'
```

The g means global, which applies the expression to each match it finds on a line, not just the first.